# Are linear transformations between two spaces with the same dimension always one to one and onto (thus bijective)?

Tags: linear-algebra

I saw a proof today that states

**Proposition**

If $\dim(V_{1}) = \dim(V_{2})$ and $T:V_{1}\to V_{2}$, $T$ is a linear transformation, then $T$ is one to one iff $T$ is onto.

But I think that every linear tranformation with $\dim(V_{1}) = \dim(V_{2})$ and $T: V_{1}\to V_{2}$ is one to one and onto. I am possibly wrong because I can only visualize transformations of the 3,2,1 dimensional vectorspace of real number.

Comment: The zero map is neither one-to-one (injective) nor onto (surjective), unless $V_1=V_2=0$.

Comment: Consider $T(x,y)=(x,0)$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ itself. Is it one-to-one?

Comment: @sangchul Lee aaah I see I was thinking about the Dimension of the Image , Yeah your absolute right

Comment: if $V,W$ are non-trivial vector spaces then every non-trivial linear function $f:V\to W$ is bijective iff $\dim(V)=\dim(W)=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is summed up in the rank-nullity theorem, which states for a linear transformation $T:V \rightarrow W$ that

$Rank(T) + Nullity(T) = dim (V)$.

Here,

$Rank(T)=dim(Image(T))$, and

$Nullity(T) = dim(Nul (T)) = dim(\{v \in V \mid T(v) = 0\})$.

Suppose that $dim(V) = dim(W)$. Recall that $T$ is one to one (also called injective) if and only if  $Nullity(T) = 0$. Hence, by the rank nullity theorem, $Rank(T) = dim(V) = dim(W)$; this is if and only if $T$ is onto (surjectivity). Conversely, $T$ is onto if and only if $Rank(T) = dim(W) = dim(V)$. Again, by the rank nullity theorem, this implies that $Nullity(T) = 0$, which is if and only if $T$ is one to one.

An plainer way to see this is the following:

Suppose $n = dim(V) = dim(W)$, and let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix for $T$. Then if $T$ is one to one, then there is a pivot in every column. Since $A$ is a square matrix, there is a pivot in every row, too. Hence, $T$ is onto. Conversely, if $T$ is surjective, then there is a pivot in every row of $A$. Since $A$ is square, this means there is a pivot in every column, which implies that $T$ is one to one.